# how to select elements by choose parameters from another table in SQLite3 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask

Is it possible to return city list (for example) from Poland (country_id = 76) but using country name (value of country.country row) in WHERE not directly country_id? The structure of database bellow.

```
@app.route('/citiess')
def city_list3():
    db = get_db()
    data = db.execute('''
        SELECT city FROM city 
        JOIN country ON city.country_id = country.country_id
        WHERE city.country_id = 76
        ''').fetchall()
    data_json = []
    for i in data:
        data_json.extend(list(i))

    return jsonify(data_json)
```

[image: database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do your `WHERE` clause on the joined `country` table, i.e.:

```
data = db.execute("""SELECT city FROM city
                     JOIN country USING (country_id)
                     WHERE country.country = ?""", ("Poland", )).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that also works:

```
data = db.execute('''
    SELECT city FROM city 
    JOIN country ON country.country_id = city.country_id
    WHERE country.country = "Poland"
    ''').fetchall()
```

anyway thanks

Comment: I just parameterized it so you can safely reuse your query for any country you want instead of changing the SQL directly.